# Creating Linked Clones in vSphere/vCenter w/ PowerCLI

Tags: clone, esxi, vcenter, vsphere

I'm fairly new to enterprise IT:
We have a 'mini cloud' server at work that everyone uses for 'training.' We have 3 host machines with multi SSD/HDDs (on the hosts and on other hardware) which we created into a SAN cluster. We use ESXI for visualization and VSphere/VCenter to manage everything.

My boss has learned about linked clone VMs recently and told me to create them. I think I understand the structure and significance of linked clones but I'm having trouble creating them.

Initially, I tried using the vSphere Client GUI to create the linked clones but there wasn't an option to do so. Now, I'm having to use PowerCLI to accomplish the task. I'm able to get into my ESXI host via PowerCLI with this command (after assigning the variables, obviously):

```
New-VM -Name "Linked_Clone_VM" -VM $sOriginalVM -Location $oLocation  -Datastore
$oDatastoreLocation -ResourcePool Resources -LinkedClone -ReferenceSnapshot $oSnap
```

**"New-VM : 3/6/2015 4:21:00 PM    New-VM        The operation for the entity "Windows7_VM" failed with the following message: "The operation is not supported on the object."**

Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: From @Kam: This article is really useful for cloning: http://michlstechblog.info/blog/vmware-vsphere-create-a-linked-clone-with-powercli/

Answer (score 0):

You need at leas PowerCLI 5.1 https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI51/html/New-VM.html

And vSphere 5.1 to create a linked clone.

I guess is not supported on older versions.